# Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma fila de espera

Tags: java, lista, ireport, fila-thread, fila

Galera, qual a melhor forma de fazer uma fila de espera em java. Por exemplo eu seleciono 3 arquivos, esses arquivos ficam em uma fila até que o processo de leitura e geração do relatório esteja finalizado, assim que o relatório é gerado o outro arquivo entra em execução.
OBS: Estou usando java desktop.
Valeu galera.

Comment: Você pode usar a classe [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), ou se você der mais detalhes da sua aplicação pode ser que descobramos outra maneira mais apropriada para resolver

Comment: Tenho uma aplicação que lê vários arquivos xml e pega os dados das tags. Com essa aplicação eu consigo selecionar o xml e logo após feito isso um relatório é gerado pelo iReport com todos os dados que pertenciam ao arquivo xml. Porém gostaria de executar apenas 1 xml por vez, por exemplo, a aplicação lê o xml gera o relatório e depois vai pro próximo arquivo e faz o mesmo. Estou tentando fazer só com ArrayList mas não está dando certo

Comment: @sinkz, o que não está dando certo? Dê mais detalhes da sua dificuldade.

Comment: @sinkz uma solução seria utilizar threads, porém não ficou clara a sua pergunta, logo recomento que explique melhor a sua necessidade para que possamos lhe ajudar.